# Google Sheets COUNTIF multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with data similar to this:

[image: Example Image]

Trying to have it check the value of ColA then check if ColB and ColC have matching values.

I tried =COUNTIFS(A:A,"One",B:B,C:C). In the example above it returns 2 when it should be 3, not sure what's happening.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
=sumproduct(A:A="One", B:B=C:C)
```